# Update Mysql Data

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Apologize me if my question is wrong. I have thousands of data to create wordpress pages. I want to create bulk page creation and tried many plugins to create bulk page creation but no use.  I couldn't create all pages one by one. So I Exported CSV data from my site wp_post. Then I added some rows data in CSV (for checking).

Then re-imported to wp_post table and update query by below code.

```
             UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_author=1
```

I check added new webpage. The page display as 404 error.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The correct query:

```
UPDATE `wp_posts` SET post_author=1 WHERE ID=your post
```